react-native-flash-message doesn't work in RN 0.75.2
I'm migrating my react native bare project to the new architecture, from 0.71 to 0.75.2 and it's all working fine, however the react-native-flash-message doesn't work, I've already verified the docs and my App.tsx has the correct structure, however when I set my sample button, it doesn't work, in my console it doesn't appear any error either.
in my package.json I've this:
"react-native": "0.75.2",
"react-native-flash-message": "0.4.1",

my App.tsx:
function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <FlashMessage position="top" />
      <Navigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;

And my Home Screen:
<Button
    onPress={() => {
    /* HERE IS WHERE WE'RE GOING TO SHOW OUR FIRST MESSAGE */
      showMessage({
       message: "Simple message",
       type: "info",
      });
   }}
   title="Request Details"
  color="#841584"
/>

Some tip for resolve this?

The document stated that the <FlashMessage> should be the last component. Try moving that below the Navigator in your App.tsx.
